# Iterating over dictionaries of lists

Tags: python

I have a dictionary (dict_of_lists) that has as its values a list of tuples (inside_list). I populate the dictionary with 10 entries, with each entry consisting of a list of 100 tuples. The code to do this is as follows:

```
inside_list = []
dict_of_list = collections.defaultdict(list)
for j in range(0, 10):
    for i in range(0, 100):
        inside_list.append((j, i))
    dict_of_list[j].append(inside_list)
```

Now, to iterate the dictionary and print just the second value of all the tuples in the lists inside_list (that is, the j values), I was thinking that I would need to use 2 for loops, one to iterate the dictionary, and the other to iterate the inside_list. So I wrote the following:

```
for k in dict_of_list.keys():
    for item in dict_of_list[k]:
        print(item[1])
```

However, the results that I recive is:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
```

My question is, why isn't "item" the tuples of the lists inside_list, and instead, it looks that it's the complete inside_list instead?

To fix this, I added another for loop:

```
for k in dict_of_list.keys():
    for item in dict_of_list[k]:
        for x in item:
          print(x[1])
```

But then, what was the use of the for loop statement "for item in dict_of_list[k]" in the first place?

Comment: Because each `item` is `dict_of_list[k]`. Why would you expect that to be a tuple? What does `dict_of_list` hold?

Comment: I'm expecting each item to be of type inside_list. Since that's what's I append in "dict_of_list[j].append(inside_list)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `dict_of_list[j].append(inside_list)`, so `dict_of_list[j]` is `[ [ (x,x),(x,x) ] ]` (a list with a single element, which is a list of tuples. You probably want

```
dict_of_list[j] = inside_list
```

instead, in which case you don't need `defaultdict` at all. Also note that all elements of `dict_of_list` are the same single list (with 1000 elements), if you want distinct lists, move `inside_list` initialization into the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a fake example, or do you really want lists consisting of `i,j` in this manner?

If so, there are more efficient ways to generate the list besides that inner loop:

```
dict_of_list = {}
for j in range(10):
    dict_of_list[j] = zip([j]*100,range(100))
```

Comment: It was a fake example I'm afraid. My real problem is rather complex, and would most likely prove distracting. Thanks.

Comment: I figured as much. Good luck.